# Conditional operators in Java throw an unexpected NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullPointerException through auto-boxing-behavior of Java ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763983/nullpointerexception-through-auto-boxing-behavior-of-java-ternary-operator)

The following code uses simple conditional operators.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer exp1 = true ? null : 5;
        Integer exp2 = true ? null : true ? null : 50;

        System.out.println("exp1 = " +exp1+" exp2 = "+exp2);

        Integer exp3 = false ?  5 : true ? null: 50; //Causes the NullPointerException to be thrown.

        System.out.println("exp3 = "+exp3);
    }
}
```

This code compiles fine. All the expressions ultimately attempt to assign `null` to `Integer` type variables `exp1`, `exp2` and `exp3` respectively.

The first two cases **don't** throw any exception and produce `exp1 = null exp2 = null` which is obvious.

The last case however, if you go through it carefully, you will see it also attempts to assign `null` to `Integer` type variable `exp3` and looks something similar to the preceding two cases but it causes the `NulllPointerException` to be thrown. Why does it happen?

Before I posted my question, I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098953) nice question but in this case, I couldn't find what rules as specified by JLS are applied here.

Comment: `?:` operator makes code less evident. Should you have used `if-then-else`, the confusion wouldn't have arised.

Comment: The operator didn't throw this exception. One of *your operands* threw it during evaluation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `null` is being unboxed to an `int`, because the assignment is due to the `5` an `int`, not an `Integer`. However, a `null` cannot be represented as an `int`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

If you replace `5` by `new Integer(5)`, then it'll work.

```
Integer exp3 = false ? new Integer(5) : true ? null : 50;
```

#### See also:

- [Java Language Specification - Chapter 15.25 - Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)
- [Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing)

Comment: Just to add to the explanation: The expression `true ? null : 50` in the assignment to `exp3` is being evaluated in an `int` context. When the same expression is evaluated in the assignment to `exp2`, it is in an `Integer` context.

Answer (score 2):

It is unboxing `null` so it's the same type as the other two values in the `?:` expression. `exp1` and `exp2` don't trigger this.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        Integer exp3 = false ?  5 : true ? null: 50; //Causes the NullPointerException to be thrown.
        System.out.println("exp3 = "+exp3);
    }  
}
```

After running `javap -c Foo` we get this disassembly:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   aconst_null
   1:   checkcast   #2; //class java/lang/Integer
   4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   7:   invokestatic    #4; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   10:  astore_1
   11:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   14:  new #6; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   17:  dup
   ....
```

Note 4: `invokevirtual #3` -- it's attempting to unbox `null` right there.

Comment: This is especially fun because it reveals how amusing the compiler is. It is smart enough to skip all the conditionals, but not smart enough to just replace it with `throw new NullPointerException()`

Comment: I think people may have downvoted you for being tl;dr, but I like your solution because you show the OP how to answer questions like this for himself in the future. ;)