# Java ternary operator function overloading

Tags: java, ternary-operator, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java conditional operator ?: result type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615498/java-conditional-operator-result-type)
>   [NullPointerException through auto-boxing-behavior of Java ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763983/nullpointerexception-through-auto-boxing-behavior-of-java-ternary-operator)

Say I have two functions:

```
f(MyObject o) { ... }
f(int i) { ... }
```

And I call them like this:

```
f(someCondition ? 10 : null);
```

This compiles, but when I run it I get a null pointer exception (sorry I'm not sure on which condition). Some my questions are:

1. Why does it even compile? What is the type of `foo ? 10 : null`?
2. It clearly doesn't call the "correct" functions because that wouldn't cause an NPE. So which function is it calling? Does it do `f((MyObject)10);` or `f((int)null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the problem doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you have overloaded versions of `f`. If you only have the version of `f` that takes an `int`, you get the same problem.

The thing is that both possible results of the ternary expression (before and after the `:`) must have the same type, because the whole expression `condition ? expr1 : expr2` must have a single type. You can't have this expression evaluate to one type of `condition` is `true`, and another type if it is `false`.

So, the Java compiler is going to see if it can convert `expr1` and `expr2` to a single type. Note that `int` cannot be `null` (because it's a primitive type). However, `10` can be converted to `Integer` via autoboxing, and an `Integer` can also be `null`. So the type of the whole ternary expression is determined to be of type `Integer`. The result is either an `Integer` that contains the value `10` or an `Integer` that is `null`.

Step two is that you pass this `Integer` to `f`. Because `f` takes an `int`, it is auto-unboxed.

If you auto-unbox an `Integer` that is `null`, you get a `NullPointerException` - that's what happens here.

Answer (score 2):

1. The type is `Integer` - an *auto boxing* is done to the 10.
2. `f(int)` is called, because it is the only accepted cast from Integer available (assuming no other overloads)

   When you try to cast a `null` to an `int` - you get your NPE.

<strike>2. `f(Object)` is called since Integer is an Object. This is called *reference type widening*</strike> 

(sorry for the initial mistake, read it as `f(Object)`)